# oracle10g-xe uninstall

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

i have installed Oracle 10 g Express Edition. Now I want to uninstall it . I am unable to find it in Add/Remove Programs from the Control Panel.
In the oracle website there is something mentioned about OracleXE.exe , when I run it says that OracleService is already installed try removing the components and reboot the system.

I do not want to remove/edit my system registry.
Can anyone explain me how to remove oracle 10 g Express Edition

Answer (score 3):

You need to look in the Oracle XE documentation.

Chapter 7 offers an entire section on Deinstalling Oracle XE.

For your convienience I have provided the direct link here:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/install.102/b25143/toc.htm

Hope this helps...